# simple adding of int problems - assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c

not sure why this is so difficult for me.  I have an array and I store its count like so:

```
int index = myarray.count;
```

then I have a for loop like so and I simply want to add index and my i counter below:

```
for (int i=0; i < anotherarray.count ; i++) {
  int newIndex = index + i;
}
```

this gives me the error:
**assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast**

and a crazy value

Comment: Have you copied your code here (good) or retyped it (not good)? Is the error on the line where newIndex is declared/assigned to?

Comment: Is myarray an NSArray?  Have you tried int index = (int) myarray.count;

Comment: Did you overwrite the value of index somewhere? The currently shown code is okay. The problem must be somewhere else. Where is the rror shown at?

Comment: Are you sure "index" isn't being re-defined as something else in different scopes? I tried your code and to not get the compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that index is a char * function, defined in string.h

Comment: that was my problem, changed my variable name and problem solved :)